# Create setting page using jquery mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

Dears,

I'm developing a small mobile application using JQuery Mobile, implemented on PhoneGap (cordova).

I need to create a mobile setting page, where the data entered in this page would be saved on the phone storage.

Can someone please guide me on how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use localstorage concept. When the user click the particular list item like below **save localstorage** :

```
localStorage.setItem("listitem", "1");
```

**get localstorage :**

```
alert(localStorage.listeitem)
```

for more check this url 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Do you mean that there is no special setting for creating setting page? like (data-role="settings"). Just create normal page and store the the values in local storage?

Comment: do u want mobile settings page ? or is it your own page?. and i think (data-role="settings") is not available

Comment: I want my own setting page for my application not the mobile settings